# Find Distinct results in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

Im trying to fetch Distinct records, SQL query looks as follows

```
select DISTINCT id from Table A where UserId = 'XXXX';
```

Currently, I have implemented this using spring data jpa @Query

```
@Query(value = "select DISTINCT id from Table A where UserId = :userId")
```

Can this be achived through spring data jpa query method ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. You can use the Spring boot query builder (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)) to get a simple query with distinct. In your case, the query method will look like:

```
List<Long> findDistinctIdByUserId(String userId);
```

The use of `Long` is just in case you're using a number ID in the DB - it can of course be String or any other datatype, as applicable. Same for my choice to type userId as `String`. "findDistinct" is a prefix to select all distinct results from the table, the next word is the column name, and "byColumnName" is a suffix to add the relevant Where clause (and it should correlate with the input argument to the method).

Comment: I think the answer is wrong. According to the documentation, this is not possible

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence

and

"@Query to best capture the information you seek, since you also may be needing a projection to capture the result set."

Comment: According to the same documentation you cited, it is possible. Can you direct me to where it says exactly that this is impossible? He just needs to get a distinct keyword added.

Comment: I have published additional information on this issue. Maybe we misunderstand each other a bit, but in general you can understand what I mean

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

About Distinct and JPA you can find that information in this article:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

**Table 3. Supported keywords inside method names**

Distinct (Keyword) findDistinctByLastnameAndFirstname (Sample) select distinct …​ where x.lastname = ?1 and x.firstname = ?2 (JPQL snippet)

So you can create only that type of distinct request using only JPA keywords:

select **distinct x.id, x.lastname, x.firstname x.created, x.userId**  where x.lastname = ?1 and x.firstname = ?2

But not select distinct x.userId  where x.id = ?1 as the author of the question would like (in this case you will receive) error because the original sql statement had been:

select distinct x.id, x.lastname, x.firstname x.created, x.userId....  where x.id = ?1

and mapping exception happened.

And there is a big **warning** about Distinct in JPA

> DISTINCT can be tricky and not always producing the results you
> expect. For example, select distinct u from User u will produce a
> complete different result than select distinct u.lastname from User u.
> In the first case, since you are including User.id, nothing will
> duplicated, hence you’ll get the whole table, and it would be of User
> objects. However, that latter query would narrow the focus to just
> User.lastname and find all unique last names for that table. This
> would also yield a List result set instead of a List
> result set. countDistinctByLastname(String lastname) can also produce
> unexpected results. Spring Data JPA will derive select count(distinct
> u.id) from User u where u.lastname = ?1. Again, since u.id won’t hit
> any duplicates, this query will count up all the users that had the
> binding last name. Which would the same as countByLastname(String
> lastname)! What is the point of this query anyway? To find the number
> of people with a given last name? To find the number of distinct
> people with that binding last name? To find the number of distinct
> last names? (That last one is an entirely different query!) Using
> distinct sometimes requires writing the query by hand and using **@Query**
> to best capture the information you seek, since you also may be
> needing **a projection** to capture the result set.

The key points are highlighted, so use only the JPA keyword, not enough